# C# & Entity Framework Core: error using a variable for id's when seeding with modelbuilder

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, visual-studio-2022

I am attempting to seed a database with a lot of example objects... at the moment there are 130 of them, to be exact. After a while I got tired of adding the objects into the `.HasData()` manually, and put all the objects into an array, and thought I would use a foreach loop instead.

I then quickly realized that this could potentially allow me to get around having to hard-code the object's id's as well, which had quickly turned old (especially since I sometimes have to insert objects between other objects, in an array with 60+ objects, which offsets the "flow of sequential id's") ;P

However, when I run Add-Migration [Migration-name] I get an error claiming:

> The seed entity for entity type '[MyEntity]' cannot be added because another seed entity with the same key value for {'Id'} has already been added.

My seed method is structured as follows (this is just an example):

```
public class DbInitializer
{
    private readonly ModelBuilder modelBuilder;

    // This is the id variable that I think should work...
    private int myIdVariable { get; set; }

    public DbInitializer(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        this.modelBuilder = modelBuilder;
    }

    public void Seed()
    {
        // First I set the variable to 1 (because [reasons])...
        myIdVariable = 1;

        // And I now give all the objects in the array my id variable as id...
        var Table1Array = new Table1[]
        {
            new Table1() = { Id = myIdVariable, Name = "Example1", AssMode = true },
            new Table1() = { Id = myIdVariable, Name = "Example2", AssMode = true },
            new Table1() = { Id = myIdVariable, Name = "Example3", AssMode = false },
        }

        // And I now loop the array and run .HasData() on all the entries in the array,
        // finishing off with myIdVariable++ for incremental increase.
        foreach(table in Table1Array)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>().HasData(table);
            myIdVariable++;
        }
    }
}
```

The looping works if the id's are hard-coded, so I know that isn't an issue in and of itself. However, it seems that the variable++ isn't doing the trick, as the migration-builder insta-fails.

Keep in mind that this is just an example, and I have several arrays of objects, creating a total of 130 objects (with more to come).
And one array in particular that currently holds 66 of these objects, where I sometimes have to insert a new object in between others, which offsets the hard-coded id's and is a total STD to fix to be sequential again. Hence this idea of using a variable for id.

Am I braking any rules in EFC by doing this? I mean if running `.HasData()` in a foreach works, then why doesn't the variable get an incremental increase, and is there any other way to give these objects their id sequentially without hard-coding them?

Thankful for any input.

Love & respect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the variable myIdVariable is a value type (int), the value of each Id is the value of the variable when you assigned it, even if you incremented the variable afterward.

You can either add the tables to your array inside the loop, when incrementing the value or use something like the following example.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var Table1Array = new Table1[]
        {
            new Table1() { Id = -1, Name = "Example1", AssMode = true },
            new Table1() { Id = -1, Name = "Example2", AssMode = true },
            new Table1() { Id = -1, Name = "Example3", AssMode = false },
        };

// Initial id value
var currentId = 1;

foreach (var table in Table1Array)
{
   // Update the Id
   table.Id = currentId;
   // Increment the value
   currentId++;
}

        
    }
}
```

Comment: So why bother setting `Id` to -` in the first place though?

Comment: You are correct, it is not necessary.

Comment: This solution seemed super logical, and I felt like ultra-facepalm when I realized I didn't set the table.id in the loop already - so stupid of me. But ofc, even after updating all the code to your suggestion, Add-Migration is still screaming at me. And I have to admit that now, after failing at it, I can't shake the thought that whatever I set the ID's to in the array will be an issue, unless they are different already. But I do thank you deeply for all your time and effort, it means a lot to me (as I've become borderline brain-damaged from being stuck at this for so long).

Comment: I suddenly remembered that the computer they gave me at work is completely busted, and it has given me several wierd issues that were auto-magically solved with a restart of Visual Studio... Now it wasn't that simple this time, but I had all the code setup and ready to go from the first attempt, and in the end all it took was a simple reboot and Add-Migration just went through! Thank you, thank you, thank you! Life saver!

Comment: Now, I am not sure about a lot of this, but just to be clear: I did not perform this solution as in your code example which has placed the table in Program -> Main(). It is all still in the initializer class in the DataAccessLayer with DbContext.

Answer (score 1):

So the main issue here is that int is a value type and you changing the value after you assigning the value to your objects ID. This is mentioned above so I'm not going to explain more on that part and just give you some alternatives

1. If you really want to assign ID's on your c# layer then I would suggest using guids. You can assign them to each table by saying

   Guid.NewGuid();
2. Best practice and my recommendation is to assign ID's on your your database layer. You can do this by going into your table design and finding the below settings

[IdentitySeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTzxB.png)

Identity Increment - What you want to increment by
Identity Seed - Start value

This way you dont manage unique identifiers and let SQL do that for you. Also Guids are not 100% guaranteed to generate unique values all the time

Comment: Pretend you're speaking to someone "educated" at the worst university in history - in fact, don't pretend ;)
I might be assuming something incorrectly when you say "database layer," but this is a solution with four layers; Api-, Business-, DataAccess-, and DomainModel. DataAccess is where the db context and its initializer resides, and so this is where I am tasked to fix the seeding. Btw, we are using Guid, but only for Users, as I have been told it is [only] meant for.
Guess I am just left with hard-coding the ID's in the arrays, after all. But I thank you very much for your time & effort.

Comment: No worries! glad to help. So by database layer I mean on your actual sql server instance (I'm assuming you using sql server). The most practical way it to let it seed and increment your ID's for you, the only change you will need on your data access layer which resides in your API is you remove the ID property and just pass in the rest of your values. Your model ends up looking like public string Name {get;set;}; public bool Assmode {get;set;}. Let me know if you still need more clarification and I will edit my answer (step by step) to enable sql server to increment the ID's for you :)

Comment: This sounds like the most amazingly simple way to do things. And you are correct, it is sql server... However, I do not have "the rights" to change neither the classes/models nor the actual db. Not unless there's a way to do it from the override OnModelCreating(), where I did, for instance, find a way to change the cascading deletes behavior which caused me a lot of issues during my initial Update-Database commands. Regardless, thank you once more. You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

All your entities are going to have the same ID when you create them. Instead, remove the `myIdVariable++;` line and do that inline:

```
var Table1Array = new Table1[]
{
    new Table1() = { Id = myIdVariable++, Name = "Example1", AssMode = true },
    new Table1() = { Id = myIdVariable++, Name = "Example2", AssMode = true },
    new Table1() = { Id = myIdVariable++, Name = "Example3", AssMode = false },
};
```

And since [`HasData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.hasdata?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-entitytypebuilder-hasdata(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-object)))) can take an `IEnumerable<T>` directly, you can add it in one go like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>().HasData(Table1Array);
```

Comment: This exact solution had already popped up in my brain as an alternative, and I did try it just before posting the question in the first place. And, because my code was left exactly as you are suggesting (minus adding the entire array in one go), I could try it with little-to-no-effort (after also implementing your .HasData()-suggestion). Now, I have clearly become code-blind from staring at this too long, so it could be that I messed something else up. However, Add-Migrations is still throwing a fit. But regardless, I am endlessly grateful for your time and effort - a million times thank you!